# Copying View Controller between Projects

Tags: ios

I was trying to copy this View Controller from project A:

[image]

And pasted it to my project B:

[image]

Notice the Root View Controller is now missing when pasted.

Comment: copy both navigation controller and view controller then paste it ,i think that root view controller is title for your navigation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation is root view controller for your case

> ->Navigation controller (root view controller)
>        ->view controller (present view controller)

So you need to copy it both ,then only you will get .